# How to make camera application for android 2.3?

Tags: java, android, camera

I was looking for a tutorial to create an application with a camera api for android 2.3.  If I don't have much experience with java and eclipse, how would I go about doing this?

I only want to use it to make photos with the application.

Comment: If you continue posting (non) questions like this you will receive a ban.

Comment: A word of advice, SO are for specific programming questions for developers that get stuck on something.  Not a code writing service.  You need to try something, post the code if you can't complete it or get it working, then ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic tutorial from Vogella.  His are fairly easy to follow and very detailed.  The link is [Android Camera API - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)

Just a caveat though, you shouldn't dive right into android applications off the bat if you aren't already somewhat knowledgeable in java and have experience with eclipse.  If you make a simple mistake, you can spend a lot of time trying to figure out where you went wrong.

I don't want to discourage anyone from learning anything new in programming or new technologies, just be realistic about what level you are at and what you can accomplish with your time.  You want the most benefit from the time you are putting in with your learning.